# Qlik sense embed to web site

Tags: javascript, web, qlikview, qliksense, mashup

I am trying to embed qlik sense report to my site. I have heard about two option how to do it. First is using iframe. Second using div integration.
Has anyone ever encountered this it? Which proc and cons? Do you have an example of how to do it (prefer div integration).

Answer (score 0):

In the latest versions of Qlik Sense you can just right click on any object you want to embed and from the context menu you can select Embed object and that will give you the configuration options and the iframe embed link for the chosen object. I think this is the preferred method from Qlik and will provide you with a live object adhering to all the Sense governance rules and security.

I don't have any insight into how the div version would work or what the pros and cons of that might be